# How to create more than 46K Global Reference?

Tags: android, memory, xamarin, garbage-collection

I'm using XAMARIN to develop an Android application.
I want to re-procedure a bug about leaking to release global reference.
(To make crashing application)
I try to create many global reference (more than 52K) but when the number of Global Reference reach to ~46K, GC always try to full collect again and again so I can't create more.
Anyone know how to create more?

```
06-14 10:57:15.891 I/monodroid-gc(30078): 46196 outstanding GREFs. Performing a full GC!
06-14 10:57:17.651 I/dalvikvm-heap(30078): Clamp target GC heap from 259.249MB to 256.000MB
06-14 10:57:17.651 D/dalvikvm(30078): GC_EXPLICIT freed 14K, 2% free 256925K/261688K, paused 3ms+136ms, total 575ms
06-14 10:57:21.331 D/Mono    (30078): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 46074 objects 74803 opaque 112565 colors 47058 colors-bridged 45516 colors-visible 45516 xref 28118 cache-hit 275 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 1542 setup 10.29ms tarjan 138.36ms scc-setup 23.85ms gather-xref 7.67ms xref-setup 3.00ms cleanup 21.47ms
06-14 10:57:21.331 D/Mono    (30078): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 5078.26ms
06-14 10:57:21.331 D/Mono    (30078): GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 24096K in use: 20670K
06-14 10:57:21.331 D/Mono    (30078): GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 351.36ms, stw 354.13ms los size: 20636K in use: 3034K
06-14 10:57:21.331 I/monodroid-gc(30078): 46197 outstanding GREFs. Performing a full GC!
```

Answer (score -1):

Its bad practice to take too many global reference. Please reuse reference and use database also use constructor and good data passing methods using interface,broadcast etc

Comment: I know, but that's not my product code, it's used for testing